# Change a running application to run in background

Tags: linux, terminal, c

I'm working on this application in C, which runs in linux.
At beginning it runs normally.

~$ ./myApp

I do it this way because the user must confirm a specific step.

But after the confirmation I would like to run it in background to allow user run other processes.
But if I run the application in background from the very beginning.

~$ ./myApp &

The system won't read the keyboard hits as an answer to myApp question.

If it matters that part of the code is something like this

```
while (flag)
{
  pressedKey = getchar();
  switch(pressedKey)
  {
    //some code
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in linux or C?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, you can issue a control-Z to stop the program and issue a `bg` to let it continue in the background. So that would be:

```
~$ ./myApp
  press the any-key
  press ^Z
~$ bg
```

In C, you would typically daemonize the program, something like

```
while (flag)
{
  pressedKey = getchar();
  switch(pressedKey)
  {
    //some code
  }
}
process_id = fork();
if (process_id < 0) {
    exit(1);
}
if (process_id > 0) {
    exit(0);
}
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
do_the_stuff_in_the_background();
```